# Save background image of slide

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

Does anyone know how to save Background image of slide in powerpoint presentation (2010). Here is a part of my code where i'm trying to clear slide to get the background image but it's not quite the desired result

```
PowerPoint.Presentation p = app.Presentations.Open(slidesContainerPath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);

        string imagename;
        foreach (PowerPoint.Slide s in p.Slides) {
            imagename = s.SlideIndex.ToString() + ".jpg";
            s.BackgroundStyle = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoBackgroundStyleIndex.msoBackgroundStyleNotAPreset;
            foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape in s.Shapes)
            {
                shape.Delete();
            }                
            s.Export(imagesContainerPath + "\\" + imagename, "JPG");
        }
        if (p != null) {
            p.Close();
        }
```

Comment: check this link:  http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=9327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to help you solve a problem if you STATE the problem.
You say "it's not quite the desired result".  That could mean many things, from "nothing happens" to "my computer explodes".  ;-)

If I had to guess (and I do), I'd say that you're probably seeing every other shape deleted from the slides rather than every shape.  Instead of a foreach loop, use something like this (VB/VBA, translate as needed):

```
For x = s.Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
  sShapes(x).Delete
Next
```

That will delete ALL of the shapes on a slide.

Or just this instead of a loop:

s.Shapes.ShapeRange.Delete

Comment: Ok you are right I probably should have posted a more clearer problem :) 
But as you can see in my code there is a foreach loop that should delete all the shapes from the slide but for some unknown reasons it does not. The final solution that did the trick for me was to have 2 consecutive identical foreach loops that delete shapes. I have no idea why, probably due to some stupiditiy in the files I had. Nevertheless thank you for your effort.